# How to construct a Non Instantiable AND Non Inheritable Class in Java

Tags: java

The question says it all.
I know the Singleton pattern (with final to its class) is a solution. Are there any other possible ways we can achieve this? 
Abstracting a class makes it non-instantiable. Making it final makes it non-inheritable.
How do we combine both?

```
public final class SingletonObject
{
  private SingletonObject()
  {
    // no code req'd
  }

  /*public static SingletonObject getSingletonObject()
  {
    if (ref == null)
        // it's ok, we can call this constructor
        ref = new SingletonObject();        
    return ref;
  }*/

  public Object clone()
    throws CloneNotSupportedException
  {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException(); 
    // that'll teach 'em
  }

  private static SingletonObject ref;
}
```

Code Ref: http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/designpatterns/index.html

Comment: Well, just don't define `.getSingletonObject()`...

Comment: What is the use of having a class non-instantiable and non-iheratable, it is useless right?

Comment: It's useful if the class only has static utility methods. The common idiom is to make the class final and/or to define a private constructor. Why would one use another idiom, since this one works?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Make the constructor `private`:

```
public final class Useless {
    private Useless() {}
}
```

A private constructor is the normal object-oriented solution. However, it would still be possible to instantiate such a class using reflection, like this:

```
Constructor<Useless> con = Useless.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
con.setAccessible(true); // bypass "private"
Useless object = con.newInstance();
```

To prevent even reflection from working, throw an exception from the constructor:

```
public final class Useless {
    private Useless() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: Simple and Straight Forward. Thanks :)
Is there any other combination to achieve this, even if we have to write more code?

Comment: For argument's sake ypou can do public constructors with private inner class parameters or declared exceptions.

Comment: What is the reason behind the 'final' keyword in this case? Assuming that Useless() (the implicit constructor) is the only constructor in the class and it is marked private, it cannot be sub-classed anyway. Thoughts?

Comment: A `private` constructor avoids also inheritance , except in inner clases, because call super constructor is required, so without `final` keyword it would be ok too. But @J.CarlosNavea it could be inherit with an inner class.

Comment: @pau I usually leave off final too, but `final` publicly communicates to other devs that the class is not inheritable.

Answer (score 7):

You mean a class with static methods only? Class cannot be both final and abstract. But you can use private constructor to make it not instantinable.

```
final class StaticOnly {

    private StaticOnly() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Do not try to instantiate this");
    }

    public static String getSomething() {
       return "something";
    }
}
```

Below example will work to. You won't instantiate it because it's abstract. You won't inherit it because there is no way to call super constructor from external subclass (only inner subclass will work)

```
abstract class StaticOnly {

    private StaticOnly() {}

    public static String getSomething() {
         return "something";
    }
}
```

enum will work too

```
enum StaticOnly {
    S;

    public static String getSomething() {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

but it always have at least one instance (here it's S).

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can have an enum without any instances, just remember to place the ';' before defining members.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the simplest Singleton pattern

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

The `enum` type is non-instance-able and non-inheritable and the classes initialisation is lazy and thread safe.

To declare there should never be an instance you can also use an enum

```
enum Utilities {
    ; // no instances

    // add static methods here
}
```

Comment: It has one instance - INSTANCE. Singleton.INSTANCE gets an instance of that class.

Comment: The Singleton can still implement interfaces, have fields and methods like a normal class.

Comment: Dude, he does not want it instantiatable at all. No instances. When you do Singleton.INSTANCE you create an instance of the Singleton.

Comment: I didn't notice the question was edited after I answered. Thank you.