# How to create a class which is not inheritable and static in java?

Tags: java

Can you please help me how to create a class which is not inheritable and should be static in behavior (Means we should not be able to create instance of it). I need this class to store constant values. Thanks.

Comment: "Static in behaviour" is not a meaningful description.  The "static" modifier is actually allowed on some classes (i.e. inner ones), and it means something different.  What you really should be asking is how to make a class non-inheritable and *non-instantiable*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to construct a Non Instantiable AND Non Inheritable Class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848107/how-to-construct-a-non-instantiable-and-non-inheritable-class-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `final` keyword to class can not be inherited.
But I would recommend you to Use `Enums`. `Enums` can not be inherited and only one instance exists per constant value. Also you can do lot more with `enums`.

```
public enum DaysOfweek
{
    SUNDAY,MONDAY.....
}
```

You can read more about Enums here [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: You can have `enum Singleton { INSTANCE; ... }` and even `enum Static { ; ... }`.

Comment: I use the former for stateless singletons and the later for Utility classes.

Answer (score 9):

```
public final class MyClass { 
    private MyClass() { }
}
```

The `final` keyword makes it not inheritable, and making the constructor(s) `private` will help stopping it from being instantiated.

Comment: Make all constructors private, and then no one but the class itself can make instances of it.

Comment: He should use `enums` ,if he is designing class to storing constants.

Comment: @AmitD: A valid point. It would be better if OP would tell us what kind of constants they are.

Comment: This is singleton method and can be used as a workaround.. I'm looking for a direct way. In C# we can go for static class to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use an interface which has a couple of static and final variables?

Answer (score 3):

- For the first case, you can use `final` class as they can't be inherited..
- For your second case, you can use `interface`, they are very well used to store `Constants`.

But you **cannot** have both of them **together** (As having an `interface` which cannot be `implemented` does not make sense).. 
So, the best is you can mix the property of both in one class.. You can have a `final class` with `public static final` variables, as this is what makes a variable `constant` in interface, will serve the purpose of `constants`..

```
public final class A {
    public static final int YOUR_CONST = 5;

}
```

If you don't want to make instance of this class, you can have a `private 0-arg constructor` in it..

```
public final class A {
    public static final int YOUR_CONST = 5; 

    private A() {}

}
```

Comment: does it has to be 0-arg constructor?

Comment: @vandey.. Simply speaking - No.. As in this case, as this class cannot be inherited, so there won't be any problem by not defining a 0-arg constructor.. Here I've just gave an example using 0-arg constructor..

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as final which will not allow other classes to extend it, and make its constructors private so no one else (except your own class) will be able to instantiate it:

```
public final class MyClass {

    private MyClass() {
        // Private so noone else can instantiate this
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of the class to contain a constant value:

```
public final class Trial // it is the FINAL
{
    private static final int CONSTANT_VALUE = 666;

    private Trial() // it is PRIVATE instead of PUBLIC
    {
    }

    public static int getConstantValue()
    {
       return CONSTANT_VALUE;
    }
}
```

And below is an example of how to test the above class:

```
public class Bully //extends Trial ////"extends" WILL NOT COMPILE
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Trial trial = new Trial(); ////"new Trial()" WILL NOT COMPILE

        // The only thing can be done is getting a constant value from "Trial"
        int acquiredValue = Trial.getConstantValue();
        System.out.println(acquiredValue);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps  :))

Answer (score 1):

```
public final class MyClass {
    public static string MY_STRING;
    public static int MY_INT;

    private MyClass() {}
}
```

Comment: In Java, a class cannot be both `abstract` and `final` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2

Answer (score 1):

final  : Make a class final that means this class can not be inherite further more.
static : If all methods are static the you do not need to create instance of this class. and should be static in behavior.

Singleton pattern : If your all methods are not static and you do not want to create more than one instance then you can make constructor private and keep one variable of class object in the class. And create once if it is null, and if not null then return same instance always.

Thanks