# How to declare a Java class that must not be instantiated or subclassed

Tags: java

I have some java classes that only have public static final properties and/or static methods.
I don't want these classes to be subclassed or instantiated.
Since a java class cant be both abstract and final how should I declare such class ?

The Java version I'm using :

```
openjdk version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18
IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition 17.0.8.0 (build 17.0.8+7)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM 17.0.8.0 (build openj9-0.40.0, JRE 17 Windows 11 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20230718_493 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - d12d10c9e
OMR      - e80bff83b
JCL      - 77b0f754805 based on jdk-17.0.8+7)
```

Comment: Give it a private constructor.

Comment: Normally you just override the default (no-argument) constructor: `private MyClass() {}` and you're done.  You could give it any constructor, which would cause the no argument constructor to not be made by default, but ime the convention is to just override the default one (unless you plan on actually using the constructor).

Comment: "cant be" = can not be -
Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks for the link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848107/how-to-construct-a-non-instantiable-and-non-inheritable-class-in-java

it was great